# In Oracle RAC, will an application be faster, if there is a subset of the code using a separate Oracle service to the same database?

Tags: service, oracle11gr2, oracle-rac

For example, I have an application that does lots of audit trails writing.  Lots.  It slows things down.  If I create a separate service on my Oracle RAC just for audit CRUD, would that help speed things up in my application?

In other words, I point most of the application to the main service listening on my RAC via SCAN.  I take the subset of my application, the audit trail data manipulation, and point it to a separate service listening but pointing same schema as the main listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with anything else, it depends.  You'd need to be a lot more specific about your application, what services you'd define, your workloads, your goals, etc.  Realistically, you'd need to test it in your environment to know for sure.

A separate service could allow you to segregate the workload of one application (the one writing the audit trail) from the workload of other applications by having different sets of nodes in the cluster running each service (under normal operation).  That can help ensure that the higher priority application (presumably not writing the audit trail) has a set amount of hardware to handle its workload even if the lower priority thread is running at full throttle.  Of course, since all the nodes are sharing the same disk, if the bottleneck is disk I/O, that segregation of workload may not accomplish much.

Separating the services on different sets of nodes can also impact how frequently a particular service is getting blocks from the local node's buffer cache rather than requesting them from the other node and waiting for them to be shipped over the interconnect.  It's quite possible that an application that is constantly writing to log tables might end up spending quite a bit of time waiting for a small number of hot blocks (such as the right-most block in the primary key index for the log table) to get shipped back and forth between different nodes.  If all the audit records are being written on just one node (or on a smaller number of nodes), that hot block will always be available in the local buffer cache.  On the other hand, if writing the audit trail involves querying the database to get information about a change, separating the workload may mean that blocks that were in the local cache (because they were just changed) are now getting shipped across the interconnect, you could end up hurting performance.

Separating the services even if they're running on the same set of nodes may also be useful if you plan on managing them differently.  For example, you can configure Oracle Resource Manager rules to give priority to sessions that use one service over another.  That can be a more fine-grained way to allocate resources to different workloads than running the services on different nodes.  But it can also add more overhead.

Comment: Thanks.  It's all one application.  When a person saves something, it writes to a table in the schema.  Updates, etc.   It is the same schema and application.